# Uploading image constructed from byte array to Azure without saving locally

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a function that takes a byte array as an argument, uses bytesIO and constructs it into an image, and uploads it to azure blob storage.

It's supposed to look like this:

```
def foo(b):
  img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
  container_client = ContainerClient.from_conenction_string(connection_string, container_name)
  blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client('fileUpload')
  blob_client.upload(img)
```

But I get the error `seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60704712/upload-an-image-to-blob-storage-from-a-stream-in-python) but could not get it to work for me.

complete error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\WaitingRoom\uploadingfiles\form_recog.py", line 48, in <module>

    blob_client.upload_blob(img)

  File "C:\Users\355149\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\355149\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 706, in upload_blob

    options = self._upload_blob_options(

  File "C:\Users\355149\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 361, in _upload_blob_options

    length = get_length(data)

  File "C:\Users\355149\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\request_handlers.py", line 87, in get_length

    data.seek(0, SEEK_END)

TypeError: seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: You aren't even using seek. Can you please show the complete error traceback?

Comment: @mkrieger1 edited OP

Comment: `img` is not a byte array.  It is a PIL `Image` object.  It doesn't support all the options of seek.  Did you intend to feed the `io.BytesIO` object to `upload`?

Comment: like just doing `blob_client.upload(io.BytesIO(b))`? I don't think that would work for me cause I need to get it into blob storage as an image file (png or jpg doesn't matter). It's my first time working with BytesIO and Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with getting bytes from image  for **testing purpose** and upload that bytes to azure blob you can pass your input bytes of image to azure blob using `upload_blob` function

```
import os
import io
from PIL import Image
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from array import array

def readimage(imagepath):
    count = os.stat(path).st_size / 2
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return bytearray(f.read())

bytes = readimage("pathtoimage") // getting bytes of image
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes))
print("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")
#print(bytes)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("Connection String")
# Initialise container
blob_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
# Get blob
blob_client = blob_container_client.get_blob_client("test.jpg// blob name ")
blob_client.upload_blob(bytes) // uploaded blob with bytes
```

**OUTPUT**

The images uploaded as `test.jpg`

[image]

Comment: im still getting the seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given error, any ideas? i did it exactly how you did

Comment: never mind! i was uploading the image not the bytes, thank you!!!