# Is there a way to directly upload a 'generated barcode' .png file onto azure blob storage?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm having issues with directly upload a generated barcode .png file of type 'code128' onto my azure-blob-storage account, without storing to any local storage on my azure function app.

I have had success directly uploading files like .txt, .csv, and .json where the contents of the file are just strings, however, when I use the same approach to my barcode image file, I am receiving a 500 error, because the parameter can only be of type byte or string for the 'upload_blob()' function I am using to actually upload the file onto blob storage.

I want to be able to upload a .png file containing a 'code128' barcode onto blob, directly.

I have already viewed Gaurav's answer from this link: [Upload an image to Blob Storage from a stream (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60704712/upload-an-image-to-blob-storage-from-a-stream-in-python) , however, this method makes use of the matplotlib library. I tried using this library to generate my barcode but I was not successful. It also seems inefficient to use this library to generate a barcode when there are others that accomplish the same in fewer lines of code.

I have been playing around with this project for a few months with no luck, so I would really appreciate any help!

Below is a snippet of my code so far. I have abbreviated parts of it, but here is the main purpose behind it:

```
import azure.functions as func
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

barcodeContents = "1234567890" #This is a user-entered string so it's not constant
generatedBarcode = barcode.get('code128', barcodeContents, writer=ImageWriter())

name = "barcode.png"
connect_str = "<connectionString>"
container = "<containerName>"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container,blob=name)
blob_client.upload_blob(generatedBarcode, overwrite=True) # First parameter throws typeError because it is of type "barcode.codex.Code128" when only string and byte is accepted
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially, I tried with same code I got an similar error.

**Console:**

[image]

I tried with below code and barcode uploaded successfully.

**Code:**

```
import  barcode
from  barcode.writer  import  ImageWriter
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

barcodeContents = "1234567890"
barcode_format = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
generatedBarcode = barcode_format(barcodeContents, writer=ImageWriter()
hello=generatedBarcode.save("generated_barcode")
connect_str = "<connect_string>"
container = "test"
name="generated_barcode.png"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container,blob=name)
blob_client.upload_blob(hello, overwrite=True)
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Generate Barcode using Python - Python Programming - PyShark](https://pyshark.com/generate-barcode-using-python/)

Comment: Thanks, @Venkatesan,  I believe this should work, but I'm having issues with using the ImageWriter() function inside the function app. Thus, I am unable to actually render an image file (i.e., png file). When you ran your code in the function app, did you encounter a similar problem? I was able to import the ImageWriter() function, I'm just unable to use it inside my code....